# Getting "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id" error while running multiple test cases

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The aim was to execute all test cases at the same time but its not working. When executing them separately they are running successfully.

```
errororg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
Build info: version: '4.9.0', revision: 'd7057100a6'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [40f27c9d62b0d992228d008cc9e59bc2, switchToFrame {id=null}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 112.0.5615.140, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58299}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:58299/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 112.0.5615.140, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 40f27c9d62b0d992228d008cc9e59bc2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried?